# Google chart drawing line on edge of chart

Tags: charts, google-visualization

The 0 and -5 gridlines on vaxis are useless, since my data is around -10. However is not adding -15. Any help? I am sure there must be an option.

Check it here:
https://jsfiddle.net/h6u4pa2d/9/

```
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart', 'line']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {

  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [1, -10],   [2, -10.5],  [3, -10.25],
    [4, -9.75],   [5, -10],  [6, -10.25]
  ]);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity'
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use config option `vAxis.viewWindow` to set the `min` & `max` values for the axis

```
  viewWindow: {
    min: -10.5,
    max: -9.75
  }
```

if you want to avoid hard-coding values,
you can use data table method --> `getColumnRange(colIndex)`

this will return an object with the `min` & `max` values of the column

```
var range = data.getColumnRange(1);

  viewWindow: {
    min: range.min,
    max: range.max
  }
```

or if you want a little room on the edges

```
  viewWindow: {
    min: Math.floor(range.min),
    max: Math.ceil(range.max)
  }
```

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {packages: ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawBasic);

function drawBasic() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'X');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Dogs');

  data.addRows([
    [1, -10],   [2, -10.5],  [3, -10.25],
    [4, -9.75],   [5, -10],  [6, -10.25]
  ]);

  var range = data.getColumnRange(1);

  var options = {
    hAxis: {
      title: 'Time'
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: 'Popularity',
      viewWindow: {
        min: Math.floor(range.min),
        max: Math.ceil(range.max)
      }
    }
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```